# Conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value in SQL query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a simple select select statement, see below.

```
SELECT     JobTasks.JobTaskID, 
           CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(JobTasks.FileName, 2, 8), 20) 
FROM       JobTasks 
INNER JOIN JobExecutions 
ON         JobTasks.JobExecutionID = JobExecutions.JobExecutionID 
INNER JOIN JobStatus 
ON         JobExecutions.JobStatusID = JobStatus.JobStatusID 
WHERE      (JobExecutions.JobID = 1) 
AND        (JobTasks.FileName IS NOT NULL)    
ORDER BY   CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(JobTasks.FileName, 2, 8), 20)
```

It fails on converting the varchar to a date time, but if I change the select part of the script to include the filename field without the convert part it never fails, like below:

```
SELECT JobTasks.JobTaskID, CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(JobTasks.FileName, 2, 8), 20), JobTasks.FileName
```

I have checked the data and it is all correct and can be converted to a datetime without issue. I have stripped out all the non numeric characters from the data and converted them all to datetime using `CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(JobTasks.FileName, 2, 8), 20)` without issue. The field FileName is  a varchar(200) datatype. Removing or changing the order by does not make any difference. It still doesn't allow it to run

The filenames have a naming convention of

> A20120224_ABC_DEF.txt
>   B20120225_XYZ_ABC.txt
>   C20120225_XYZ.txt
>   A20120225_ABX.txt

**FYI**

This is an old system that was built using sql server 2008r2 and has been in use for several years, the issue has only just cropped up very recently. Date wasn't a datatype when it was built and I believe datetime type 20 is being used because this data is being inserted into another datetime field.

Can anyone shed some light on the reason for this?

Thanks
Noelle

**EDIT**

From the answers and comments below and further research I have come to to the following understanding:

Adding the field being used in the where clause alters the execution path of the select statement, in that it excludes the null values before it tries to cast them, where as excluding it from the select doesn't invoke the where clause until after it tries to cast them.

Would this be correct?

Comment: Please, add some data example.

Comment: @McNets I have added some same filenames, is that the sample data you were looking for?

Comment: @Noelle - What is the JobTasks.FileName data type? Is there a reason you've selected the DATETIME style of 20? Is there a need to use the TIME component of DATETIME? It seems like you're only looking for the date (depending on the version of SQL Server you're using, you may want to switch to DATE instead of DATETIME--maybe...depends on what you're doing following the select.

Comment: @Noelle - thanks for the updated information. Can you run the above query without the ORDER BY statement and find out if the error goes away? It really "sound like" there is one or more values in the field that is not formatted correctly and is breaking the CONVERT. Jerb has a great recommendation below to use TRY_CONVERT and find out what happens there...

Comment: Hmmm...that's a bummer. So, you're stuck with DATETIME, and cannot use TRY_CONVERT. I would highly recommend selecting all of the JobTasks.FileName, and exporting the values to a "good" text editor (NotePad++) to find out exactly what is stored in that field. Another thing you could try is using LTRIM in your statement--this would only "fix" any filenames that have any leading spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have checked the data and it is all correct and can be converted to a datetime without issue.

Have you checked this for all the data in the tables or just the rows that the query will return? In any case what did you do to check this?

I suspect there is data in there, that is not pulled out by the query after all filters are applied, that does not convert as desired. Including the column directly in the outputs may make the query planner go a different way around, perhaps performing the sort required to enforce the `ORDER BY` before applying the filtering clauses (where otherwise it filters first taking out the rows that cause problems). Posting query plans for each case would be helpful to confirm/disprove this.

NOTE: if there is data where characters 2-to-9 are not a valid date you may have to check for this (with `TRY_CONVERT`) in the `ORDER BY` clause as you can't guarantee the order the query planner won't go the other way around at some point in the future anyway. In fact `TRY_CONVERT` would work directly in place of `CONVERT` here, as it returns `NULL` if the value doesn't convert so the order would not error.

Are you sure that `20` is the format you want to give to `CONVERT`. This is `YYYY-MM-DD` where your data is in `YYYYMMDD` format so `112` would be correct. I don't think this would cause the error you are seeing though as the conversion works in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

I think you'll only get the out-of-range error if you try to convert, say a "June 31st" or a 13th month. If the text is just totally un-datelike (is that a word?) it'll give a different error.

With that inb mind, TRY_CONVERT() is a variant of CONVERT() which won't error if the format isn't quite right. You can use it to look for filenames which'll fail the convert.

Try running:

```
SELECT JobTasks.FileName
FROM   JobTasks 
WHERE  TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(JobTasks.FileName, 2, 8), 20) is null
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that you've tagged the question as being 2008 R2, presumably `TRY_CONVERT()` won't work for you.

This is a problem that the company I work for frequently have with data imports. What we've found is that even if your `WHERE` clause is set up so that only "valid" values should be returned, that you can still get the error if any row in the table would be invalid for the conversion.

The solution that's worked for me in these scenarios is to move the data into a temporary table without converting (but including conditions in the `WHERE` clause that helped assure that the data pulled fits the conditions). Then, select the resulting temp table data with the conversion after that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will work for your scenario, but you 'might' try using the [IsDate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql) function to verify your data.  The last two rows in my sample data are invalid date strings and return NULL due to the `CASE` expression.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Filename VARCHAR(200))

INSERT INTO @T (Filename)
VALUES ('A20120224_ABC_DEF.txt')
    ,('B20120225_XYZ_ABC.txt')
    ,('C20120225_XYZ.txt')
    ,('A20120225_ABX.txt ')
    ,('A20120230_ABX.txt ') --invalid date
    ,('A2012022_ABX.txt ') --invalid date

SELECT CASE 
        WHEN isdate(SUBSTRING(Filename, 2, 8)) = 1
            THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(Filename, 2, 8), 20)
        ELSE NULL
        END
FROM @T
ORDER BY CASE 
        WHEN isdate(SUBSTRING(Filename, 2, 8)) = 1
            THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(Filename, 2, 8), 20)
        ELSE NULL
        END
```

Results

```
| DateField     |           |
|---------------|-----------|
| NULL          |           |
| NULL          |           |
| 2012-02-24 00 | 00.00.000 |
| 2012-02-25 00 | 00.00.000 |
| 2012-02-25 00 | 00.00.000 |
| 2012-02-25 00 | 00.00.000 |
```

Comment: thanks for you input but the data is valid or its null. I believe the issue to be the execution path of the sp, in that it is trying to cast null but null should be excluded, but it is not getting excluded until after it tries to cast it.